# Can i preselect local path when saving a File?

Tags: php

Is there a possibility to preselect a local path when downloading a file via php script ?

What I mean is, if I download a file, the browser prompts a window to select download location, if there was no permanently path set. Since there are many OS out there with different fileroots which structure I don't know, I wanted to give the user of my webapplication the possibility to save the savepath to a database. And if he starts a export and file is getting downloaded that the path were the file goes is presetted. Is this possible ? Sorry for my english :D

I searched google without results... may im looking wrong ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because of security issues. You cannot access users' filesystem via browser without their knowledge - A user has to pick a file/directory/path to save something by their own.

Comment: im aware of the security issue. But actually it isn't kind of hidden. What i want is only to send a string to the browser. Not to the filesystem. Is it a access of the filesystem if i 'manipulate' the browsers prompt ?