# can we auto finish upload file from a path?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have upload file example like this :

```
<form id="form" action="http://example.com">
    <input type="file" id="file">
</form>

document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

Now, I do not want to select file,I want it auto, I have the file location like this.

```
D:\test\test.doc
```

Can jquery auto select file in a path before submit ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i preselect local path when saving a File?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846145/can-i-preselect-local-path-when-saving-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

If this could be done, than anyone could steal your files using simple script.